# Editing text file?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a text file which has a lot of lines of information, what I am trying to do is search every line that begins with `_` once I have found this line copy the line which is 6 lines below and add it to the 1st line below and delete the other rows of information.

For example:

```
_
Blue 
X
X
X
X
10.5
X
X
X
_
Orange 
X
X
X
X
15.1
X
X
X
_
```

I want to display as

```
Blue 10.5
Orange 15.1
```

I'm currently using VS 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `IO.StreamReader` to read the lines of the file:

```
Dim sr As New StreamReader(sFilePath)
```

And then loop the lines and do the things you asked:

```
Dim sLine, sResult As String
Dim iCont As Integer = -1

sResult = ""
sLine = sr.ReadLine()

While Not sr.EndOfStream
    If sLine.StartsWith("_"c) Then iCont = 0

    Select Case iCont
        Case 1
            sResult &= sLine & " "
        Case 6
            sResult &= sLine & Environment.NewLine()
    End Select

    If iCont >= 0 Then iCont += 1
    sLine = sr.ReadLine()
End While

sr.Close()
MessageBox.Show(sResult)
```

**EDIT:**
If you want to write it to a file then:

```
Dim sw As New StreamWriter(sNewFilePath)

sw.Write(sResult)
sw.Close()
```

If you didn't need anything else you can do this too:

```
IO.File.WriteAllText(sNewFilePath, sResult)
```

**Documentation**:

- [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx)
- [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- [WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx)

Comment: Thanks I tried what you suggested and have the result showing in a message box, would I need to have a StreamWriter to save it to a new textfile?